# How to define relationships without a foreign key in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have three tables

```
prices
   timestamp : datetime
   unit_id   : integer
   price     : decimal

sales
   timestamp : datetime
   unit_id   : integer
   price     : decimal

schedules
   timestamp : datetime
   unit_id   : integer
   status    : string
```

These tables don't belong to anything, so a schedules_id or other keys will not work. How can I take advantage of ActiveRecords relationships to get something like:

```
class Schedules
   has_one :sale, 
     joins: "LEFT OUTER JOIN ( sales s ) 
             ON ( s.timestamp = schedules.timestamp AND s.unit_id = schedules.unit_id")

   has_one :price
      ...
 end
```

So then I can

```
Schedules.where(timestamp: Time.now).includes([:sales, :prices]).all
```

The reality is much more complicated than the above example. The application has hundreds of tables.

Using a join works, but will place the attribute/value into the schedule object.

```
class Schedules
  def self.prices
    select("*").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN ...")
  end
end
```

The above will work in joining the `prices` fields into a schedule.

```
s = Schedules.prices.last # will have a price attribute
s.price
```

But what would be ideal is to have the joins in a child object

```
s.price.price
s.sales.price
```

Comment: If the application has hundreds of tables then you need to rethink the data structure. Something needs to be inherit from something, or reduce the number of needed tables by use of something like H-store http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a unti model, even if its just an ID number, and then enforce that they either all have the same timestamp, or just have the timestamp on the unit. Either way you end up with the same result.

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :unit
  has_one :schedule, :through unit
  has_one :sale, :through unit

end
```

Same for the other two and then.

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :price
  has_one :schedule
  has_one :sale

end
```

With either a timestamp on the Unit now instead of the others, or a custom validation to make sure that all the associated have the same timestamp.

Comment: That is a good idea for the scenario I posted.  The reality is much more complicated.  There are many more tables and possible combinations. The volume of data is also very large.  Maintaining and processing something like Unit for the many combinations would be too expensive.